# Element in jquery unable read css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've css style and jquery script at the same file. But my element in jquery is unable to read the css. Element that should take part are li,label, .selector, button. And also when I "Click Here" no alert come out.

Here is my jquery script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        //type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.1.17.20:8040/services/getArticle",
        success: function (data) {

            var data2 = data.result.target;

            btnTarget="<ul>";
            for(var i=0; i<data2.length; i++){

                btnTarget += "<li'><input id='"+data2[i].id+"' type='checkbox'>";
                btnTarget += "<label for='"+data2[i].id+"'>"+data2[i].target_name+"</label></li>";            
            } 

            btnTarget += "</ul>";  
            btnTarget += "<button type='button' id='btnMenu'>Click Here</button>"  

            $(".selector").append(btnTarget);

        },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);}
    });
});

$("document").on("click", "#btnMenu", function(){
        alert("You Click");
 });



var nbOptions = 8;
    var angleStart = -360;

    // jquery rotate animation
    function rotate(li,d) {
        $({d:angleStart}).animate({d:d}, {
            step: function(now) {
                $(li)
                   .css({ transform: 'rotate('+now+'deg)' })
                   .find('label')
                      .css({ transform: 'rotate('+(-now)+'deg)' });
            }, duration: 0
        });
    }

    // show / hide the options
    function toggleOptions(s) {

        $(s).toggleClass('open');
        var li = $(s).find('li');
        var deg = $(s).hasClass('half') ? 180/(li.length-1) : 360/li.length;
        for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
            var d = $(s).hasClass('half') ? (i*deg)-90 : i*deg;
            $(s).hasClass('open') ? rotate(li[i],d) : rotate(li[i],angleStart);
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click','.selector button',function(e){
        toggleOptions($(this).parent());
    });
```

This is a part of html file.

```
<section class="content">
                <!-- Your Page Content Here -->
                <div class="row">
                <!-- right column -->
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- Horizontal Form -->
                    <div class="box box-info">
                      <!-- form start -->
                      <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="box-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="selector">

                            </div><!-- /.selector -->
                          </div>
                        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                      </form>
                    </div><!-- /.box -->
                  </div><!--/.col (right) -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </section>
```

Here also i put some css style. This is only few. The css style is too long

```
.selector button:hover { background: #3071a9; }

.selector button:focus { outline: none; }

.selector ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
}

.selector li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.selector li input { display: none; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, can you provide more information?

Comment: Can you include the HTML?

Comment: Do you mean that your <ul> block is not being added to the element with class "selector"? or do you mean that it's being added but the style is wrong?

Comment: <ul> block is added but no css applied. @alain Nisam

Comment: Can you post the CSS styling where it appears in your files?

Comment: I just update my file..@BurningLights

Comment: It should should display circular menu around button "Click Here". But it show nothing when I click that button. It also not apply -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this:

```
$("#btnMenu").on("click",function(){
    alert("You Click");
});
```

btnMenu does not yet exist, so it isn't able to bind the eventHandler.  You could do use event delegation like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnMenu", function(){
    alert("You Click");
});
```

and it will work.

For the css, my first thought is that it has to do with this:

```
<li'>
```

See the stray single quote?  Probably messing stuff up down the line.  Also, a lot of your jquery is outside of `$(document).ready(function(){` so it may be running too early.

Comment: Hi @dave., ya its works. i will update my code. thanks alot and very apprieciate. And thanks also to others

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (cleaned up some single quotes:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        //type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.1.17.20:8040/services/getArticle",
        success: function (data) {

            var data2 = data.result.target;

            btnTarget="<ul>";
            for(var i=0; i<data2.length; i++){

                btnTarget += "<li><input id="+data2[i].id+" type='checkbox'>";
                btnTarget += "<label for="+data2[i].id+">"+data2[i].target_name+"</label></li>";            
            } 

            btnTarget += "</ul>";  
            btnTarget += "<button type='button' id='btnMenu'>Click Here</button>"  

            $(".selector").append(btnTarget);

        },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you should get in the habit of doing this in case elements you are adding listeners to don't yet exist in the DOM:

```
$(document).on("click",$("#btnMenu"),function(){
    alert("You Click");
});
```

Instead of:

```
$("#btnMenu").on("click",function(){
    alert("You Click");
});
```